# Android: If an element is deprecated at a certain API level, is it only for that API level and above?

Tags: android, api, deprecated

If an element was deprecated in API level 11, is it considered a deprecated element (not to be used if it can be helped) in API levels below 11 also or just 11 and above? If I am writing an app for API level 8, should I care about an element that was deprecated in API level 11?

This is slightly confusing to me. In Android API, for the SQLiteDatabase class for example, the method setLockingEnabled(boolean lockingEnabled) says:
This method was deprecated in API level 16. This method now does nothing. Do not use.

Does that mean it does nothing for all API levels below also or just API level 16 and above?

And if you are working on professional, commercial software, how important is it to avoid deprecated elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If an element was deprecated in API level 11, is it considered a deprecated element (not to be used if it can be helped) in API levels below 11 also or just 11 and above?

Just 11 and above.

> If I am writing an app for API level 8, should I care about an element that was deprecated in API level 11?

"Deprecated" in Android usually means "we think that there is a better solution that you should consider, but we will support this old approach as best we can as long as we can". While you should endeavor to stop using deprecated methods, that's not something you should panic about and drop everything to address right away, and often times you *need* the deprecated materials for older Android OS levels, before they were deprecated.

> Does that mean it does nothing for all API levels below also or just API level 16 and above?

Since they said "now does nothing", it is safe to say that it did something (non-nothing?) previously.

> And if you are working on professional, commercial software, how important is it to avoid deprecated elements?

In the specific case of this method, I'd skip using it, though that's more due to the nature of this method.

As a counter-example, the way preference screens are set up differs substantially in API Level 11+ (`PreferenceFragment` and `PreferenceActivity`) versus before (`PreferenceActivity` alone). You can't avoid the deprecated element on older devices, simply because there is no viable alternative (e.g., backport of `PreferenceFragment`).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. And I have a question about between the SDK version and the phone's OS version. If I use a deprecated method, it can be complied by the latest SDK and works well on the newest OS. I get a warning message now. But, Is it possible that I cannot compiled a deprecated method with a newly-released SDK later?

Comment: @cmcromance: Every now and then, Google removes a method entirely from the SDK. It does not happen very often, and usually only on fairly obscure things (so few apps will break as a result of the method's removal).

Comment: @CommonsWare THANK YOU SO MUCH! I really needed to know about it! :)

Answer (score 2):

From the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Deprecated.html)

> Annotation type used to mark program elements that should no longer be used by programmers. Compilers produce a warning if a deprecated program element is used.

I would suggest trying not to use them at all when possible. When you do I would take into consideration that this object, method, etc...may not work at some point in the future. When you build an app you typically want to build it so it can be easily maintained and flexible in the future. For this reason, I wouldn't use them if not necessary and there is almost always another way to do something

Answer (score 2):

It's worth mentioning that sometimes a method may become "undeprecated" (if that is a real word). For example, the WebSettings [setLayoutAlgorithm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setLayoutAlgorithm%28android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm%29) method was deprecated in 4.0.1, then later reinstated in 4.0.3 just with one of the algorithms deprecated.

But in general it's safe to use the method on versions of the API prior to when it was deprecated, and not recommended afterwards. Just be aware that it may not always be as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

When an item is deprecated that means that it should no longer be used after the API level in which it was deprecated. It is safe to use it for earlier API levels but if you are developing for newer API levels it should not be used. A deprecated method/element/etc. can be removed at a future point, so though it may still work now, you could end up with unwanted results in the future.

When it says that the method now does nothing that means that it no longer does anything in API 16 and above (or above 16 can't remember but to be safe I'll say 16+).